# Strong Bertrand postulate

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Is it known that for every epsilon there is `N_0` such that all intervals of the form [N, (1+\epsilon)*N], where N > `N_0`, contain prime numbers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This follows from the Prime Number Theorem.  Let π(n) be the number of primes less than n.  Then π(n) ~ n/log(n); it follows π((1+ε)n)-π(n) -> ∞ as n -> ∞.

Comment: How string is the statement that π(n) ~ n/log(n)? One certainly imagines it to be strong enough to say something specific about pi(n)-pi(n-1), but this is certainly not the typical Prime Number Theorem people study.

Comment: ~ has a precise definition: f(n) ~ g(n) means that 
lim_{n -> infty} f(n)/g(n)=1.  
That's strong enough to derive the desired conclusion.


Comment: Mm, yes it is so.

Answer (score 8):

If one wants an explicit bound on N<sub>0</sub>, apparently this can be gleaned from a [Ph.D. thesis by Pierre Dusart](http://www.unilim.fr/laco/theses/1998/T1998_01.pdf) (in French) which contains the result that for all x > 3275 there is a prime between x and x(1 + 1/(2 ln<sup>2</sup> x)). So we can take N<sub>0</sub> to be max(3275,exp((2 epsilon)<sup>−1/2</sup>)).

Comment: (Google Translate translates the thesis but the equations get messed up.) The statement can be found on Wikipedia:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PNT and the same is derived near the end of the paper:http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1999-68-225/S0025-5718-99-01037-6/S0025-5718-99-01037-6.pdf.